# How many orthogonal matrices are there with entries in $\{0,1,-1\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How many $n\times n$ orthogonal matrices are there with entries in $\{0,1,-1\}$?

please give some hint for the problem

Answer (score 2):

Hint: How many non-zero entries are there in each row or column?

If a matrix is orthogonal, then its rows and columns are unit vectors. With each entry being $0$, $1$ or $-1$, this means that there exists exactly one non-zero entry per row or column.

Can you finish?